# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' while printing

Tags: python

I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

when I try print the value of `b`

How can I print the value of `b`?

```
your_list=[[1010 ,2,3],[1010 ,7,8]]
b = []
c = []
d = []
for i in range(1,2):
    b = your_list[i][0]
    b = b.replace('1010 ','')
    print(b)
    c = b +","+your_list[i][1]+","+your_list[i][2]
    c = c.split(",")
    d.append(c)
```

Comment: b is of type `int`

Comment: The issue isn't when you're trying to print the value of `b`, it's when you're trying to call `replace` on an integer

Comment: initialize b as a String and then replace the value of it

Comment: can you please tell me a correct code,i'm really struggling with this one

Comment: If you want help writing some code you should at least describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to convert `integer` to `string`
after that you also have an error when concatenate

`b +","+your_list[i][1]+","+your_list[i][2]`

you need to convert also `your_list[i][1]` to str because it raise an `TypeError: must be str, not int` Error because we can concatenate str + int

```
your_list=[[1010 ,2,3],[1010 ,7,8]]                                                                                                                                               


b = []
c = []
d = []
for i in range(1,2):
        b = str(your_list[i][0])
        b = b.replace('1010','')
        print(b)
        c = b +","+str(your_list[i][1])+","+str(your_list[i][2])
        c = c.split(",")
        d.append(c)
```

Comment: Thanks @zimdero it works.!!!,now i'm able to print the value for `b`

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use replace on an Int object.

```
b = b.replace('1010 ','')
```

It is causing he error, convert it into str then use replace on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = "" // initiate a string
b = your_list[i][0] // get a int value
a = a + b // convert int to string
a = a.replace('1010 ','') // replace
```